# Proof concerning sequence and series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ be a sequence of distinct points in the interval $(a, b)$, $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ be a positive sequence such that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_n$$ converges. Define $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_np(x-s_n)$$ where $p$ is the unit step function. Show that for every continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$, we have $$\int_{a}^b f(x)\,\ dg(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_nf(s_n) $$

I'm having difficulty proving the Riemann-Stieltjes integral and looking for any help. Thanks!